# Masonry is NOT filling small GAPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ahrzey3g/1/)**

[**FULL Screen DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/stanze/ahrzey3g/1/embedded/result/)

Masonry is not filling small gaps even if there is space.

Example : 
Main Container width : 896px;

beside the first container with the orange background, there is a gap where Masonry could add one more container (Orange BG 2nd container), which is not happening. I'm not sure where I'm wrong. :-(

You need to maximize the window to see the issue.

**JS :**

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
            /* var container = document.querySelector('.masonry-container');
            var msnry = new Masonry(container, {
                itemSelector: '.itemMas',
                columnWidth: 15,
                gutter: 1,
                isFitWidth: true
            }); 
             */
            $ = jQuery;
                var $container = $('.masonry-container').masonry();
                var msnry;
                $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                    msnry = new Masonry( $container[0], {
                        itemSelector : '.itemMas',

                        isAnimated: true,
                        isFitWidth: true
                    });
                })
         });
```

Answer (score 5):

Masonry will not change the order of the elements in the document. It simply packs elements left-to-right as tightly as it can.

If you need to pack items by rearranging their layout, you want to use another library, such as [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) (made by the same author). It features a [bin-packing mode](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html) in which items can be rearranged to fit gaps.

Comment: Thanks, Isn't there a way we can do it in Library :-)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is how Masonry works. It may leave gaps. You should look at [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/), which was specifically designed to fill gaps.